# Is it possible to download HTML versions of articles available on publishers' websites?

Tags: publications, publishers, formatting, website, online-resource

I often see that articles on websites like [IEEE Xplore](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9748302) and [Springer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12346-022-00721-8) have a HTML version directly in the page and a PDF version to download. I usually prefer reading the HTML version because it is responsive to the viewport, so it is well readable on a mobile phone and on a big monitor.

I often like to download an article to read it on a phone offline while travelling, but PDF documents for printing are hard to read on a phone screen. So I would like to download the HTML version, but I don't see a way for that.

**Is there a way to download the HTML version of an article if it is available?** It can be something similar, like EPUB; the point is that it is offline and well readable on a phone screen. I won't accept that I would have a phone app for articles from a specific publisher, like the [app from RasearchGate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.researchgate.shellapp).

Comment: Save As from right clicking doesn’t work?

Comment: @JonCuster It works, and I may fall back to that. It is not good because it saves all clutter from the page around the article. Also, i have had problems with assets like images; Firefox downloads them too, but they don't show on the downloaded page.

Comment: Try to use the "reader mode" of your browser (or if your browser lacks it, find another one that offers it) and save that.

Answer (score 6):

article-downloader from the Olivetti group can do this, given the article DOI: [article-downloader](https://github.com/olivettigroup/article-downloader)

Answer (score 5):

This open-source project may be worth trying (at least for articles published by, e.g., Springer, which is listed as currently supported, unlike IEEE):

### [article-epub](https://github.com/kenkellner/article-epub)

> A command-line tool written in Python to convert scientific articles available as HTML into ePub form for reading on a supported e-reader. Uses a plugin system with a "recipe" for each supported scientific publisher. Takes an article URL, title, or (ideally) DOI as input.

Answer (score 1):

If the publisher provides only pdf format then you can't download what doesn't exist. There are, however, several pdf to html converters that run in various ways, including within browsers. That is probably your most general option. I won't suggest any and haven't evaluated them. A web search will turn them up.

As always, beware of things that collect data on yourself.

The opposite thing is also possible. Many browsers will save a page as a pdf.